# Is there a bitcoin wallet that works on Amazon Fire Phone?

Tags: wallet

Is there a bitcoin wallet that works on Amazon Fire Phone?
I can't find any.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think so, but you could always try a web wallet.

Comment: YEP: you can side load mycelium directly from the site